# Disable submit button until all the fields are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to disable the submit button until all the fields are completed. 
I have written a code for this but it isn't working. The submit button is enabled all the time even if the values are not entered in the fields. Any help please? Below is the html code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    validate();
    $('#Quarter, #Year, #LineID').change(validate);
});

function validate() {
    if ($('#Quarter').val()!="--Select Quarter--" &&
        $('#Year').val()!="--Select Year--" &&
        $('#LineID').val().length > 0
     {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Period:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Quarter", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q1", Value = "1" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q2", Value = "2" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q3", Value = "3" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q4", Value
                    = "4" }) },"--Select Quarter--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <br /> @Html.DropDownList("Year", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "2016", Value = "2016" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "2017", Value = "2017" }) },"--Select Year--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Line ID:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.floorConfig.LineID, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-4" style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
                <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Clear" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you just missing the closing bracket from your `IF` statement?  [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nek0nrga/)

Comment: i missed the bracket while posting it here..in the code its fine.

Comment: Should be fine then - check out the fiddle

Comment: looks like you have made some changes to the code. Can't I still use Html.dropdownlist and Html.Textboxfor?

Comment: Give id in dropdownlist and textboxfor

Comment: Of course you can - but I can't use razor on JSFiddle so couldn't just copy/paste your code.    Are you saying it still doesn't work now that you've fixed your js?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers : worked fine when i added "id" in Html.Textboxfor and Html.DropDownList. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers can you post missing "id" as you answer?

Comment: @83N : I had just missed out on id. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: No prob - I thought the above razor syntax would add IDs of 'Quarter' and 'Year' and 'LineID' for you... but I guess not!   Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

I need to add `id` for Quarter and Year. It works now!